# probability that out of $600$ balls chosen from $12000$ balls, $360$ of which are red and $11640$ are blue, $12$ of the $600$ chosen are red

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$360$ of $12000$ balls from a bucket are red, with the other $11640$ being blue. If we select $600$ balls, what is the probability that $12$ of them will be red?

I have tried doing $$\frac{\dbinom{360}{12}*\dbinom{11640}{588}}{\dbinom{12000}{600}}$$but the numbers come out to be way, way too large to calculate. Anyone have any idea how to answer this?

Comment: Your answer is missing a factor $11640 \choose 588$ in the numerator

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You are selecting so few balls in any of the relevant sets (reds, blues, entire set), that pretending this is drawing-with-replacement might be a good enough approximation.  In that case the answer is ${600 \choose 12}p^{12} (1-p)^{588}$ where $p = Prob(red) = 360/12000 = 0.03$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stirling's approxiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to calculate the log of large factorials
$$\log n! \approx n\log n - n + \frac 12\log(2\pi n)$$

[Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(360%20choose%2012)(11640%20choose%20588)%2F(12000%20choose%20600)) is happy to give an exact result, which is approximately $0.03472771$

The [non-replacement calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(600%20choose%2012).03%5E12*.97%5E588) ${600 \choose 12}0.03^{12}0.97^{588}\approx 0.036027$

Stirling will be much better as even the error in $12!$ is only one part in $144$.  If you do that one exactly, [the errors in $348!$ and $360!$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B1%2F12%2F360)%2F(1%2B1%2F12%2F348)) cancel to within $8$ parts in a million.

Comment: Hmm...  I wonder if this approximation is more or less accurate than the drawing-with-replacement approximation (in my other comment).  What's your gut feel?

Comment: This approximation is *excellent*, but so is the other one.  The error in $n!$ is essentially a factor $1+\frac 1{12n}$  Those will cancel quite a bit in your expression.

Comment: +1 Wow, thanks for doing this.  The with-replacement value has almost a 4% error... that's much bigger than I thought.